# Vista Sport Vintage Bicycle

Tags: product-rec

Can anyone tell me what happen to the Vista Bicycle company?  I'd like to know where to find parts, and did another company buy out Vista?

My Vista Sport 27inch 10 speed bike was purchased 40 years ago.  I live in Richmond, Va. There's a bike races coming here in a couple of weeks which got me to  dig out the Vista and clean it up.

**Edit:**
It took me a while to get back here, but I have found all the parts are SunTour parts. I have found all parts needed on EBay, except the Crankset.....I am still in need , but wonder if I can substitute the Suntour crankset set.

Comment: I would have to believe that a dozen or so companies have slapped the "Vista" label on their bikes over the years.

Comment: There are a few threads on [bikeforums](https://www.google.com/search?q=Vista+Bicycle+company+site:www.bikeforums.net) but nothing solid.

Comment: Would be awesome seeing a Vista Sport on the line next to the all those carbon fiber machines.

Comment: It would be more awesome to see it cross the finish line ahead of those plastic fantastics :)

Comment: @lee-fox It looks like you have created two accounts. If you would like them joined together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.

Answer (score 2):

In all likelihood the parts you need weren't made by Vista. The only things that are likely to be proprietary might be an "innovative" bottom bracket or perhaps the fork and headset. Most everything else would have or could have come from a third party. If you can be more specific about the parts you're looking for we can probably help – or at least commiserate…